# How to find a repeating characters in string and it should have repetition count of 2

Tags: javascript

Need to find a character which is repeated only twice out of many repeated characters in a string?

for example

```
string = "aaaavvvbbbffeee"

output:
ff
```

How I can get the result?

Comment: Did you try something to acquire the desired result?

Comment: Hello Sanjay, welcome to SO. Please take a look at [ask] a good question

Comment: i tried to split the string into array. then tried to run a loop for the array. But unable to get only the character with only 2 repetition.

Comment: Please post the code whatever you tried.

Comment: please edit your question and add the code you've tried. In this way, we will be able to both help you explaining what is wrong or what is missing and solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let string = "aaaavvvbbbffeee"
let count = {}

for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
  if (count[string[i]]) {
    count[string[i]]++;
  } else {
    count[string[i]] = 1;
  }
}

console.log(count)

for (let x in count) {
  if (count[x] == 2)
    console.log(x.repeat(2))
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```js
function getFrequency(string) {
var freq = {};
for (var i=0; i<string.length;i++) {
    var character = string.charAt(i);
    if (freq[character]) {
       freq[character]++;
    } else {
       freq[character] = 1;
    }
}

return freq;
};
frequency = getFrequency("aaaavvvbbbeeeffgg");

var res =  Object.keys(frequency).filter(function(key) {return frequency[key] === 2});


console.log(res.join())
```

Comment: this works. but i get the character which is repeated twice. I need the output to be a a string. Output: "ffgg"

Comment: just join it `res.join()`

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code it will output an array of only repeated char twice

```js
 function ReturnRepeatedCharTwice(string) {
      let a = new Set(string.split(""));
      let result = [];
      a.forEach(e => {
        if (string.split(e).length - 1 === 2) {
          result.push(e + e);
        }
      });
      return result;
    } 

//for example if we tried it with your example it will output this 

    console.log(ReturnRepeatedCharTwice("aaaavvvbbbffeee"));//['ff']

//for this example it will output this 

    console.log(ReturnRepeatedCharTwice("aavvvbbbffeee")); // [ 'aa', 'ff' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative answer for parsing strings would be to use [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). While these are on their face more obtuse, in the long run they allow you to very efficiently and quickly deal with strings.

For instance, in this case:

```js
var string1 = "aaaavvvbbbffeee";
var string2 = "aaaattvvvbbbffeeeeefeee";
console.log(string1.match(/(.)\1(?<!\1{3})(?!\1)/g));
console.log(string2.match(/(.)\1(?<!\1{3})(?!\1)/g));
```

You can find any number of sources that will break down how to build expressions (I'm partial to [regexr](https://regexr.com/) myself.)